# how to detect error in ajax file?

Tags: php, ajax

I use ajax for saving a value in db, but the problem appear in this kind of work it's hard to understand the error because it doesn't show the error like a usual php file. How can I get the error?

php file that handle the ajax request:

```
if(isset($_POST['present'])){
    $user_id=(int)$_POST['user_id'];
    $date_id=(int)$_POST['date_id'];
    $attendance_id=(int)$_POST['attendance_id'];

    $attendance=new Attendance();
    $attendance->id=$attendance_id;
    $attendance->user_id=$user_id;
    $attendance->date_id=$date_id;

    $present_ok=$attendance->save();
    echo $present_ok;
}
```

If it's OK it should return true, and data should be saved on the db but when I alert data, there is nothing to show and nothing changes in db.

Comment: where is your ajax code?

Comment: Open your browsers development code and take a look.

Comment: my ajax code is ok, i want to know is there any way to get back db error or not

Comment: @arkascha i use chrome, what should i do? or in firefox

Comment: Mock `$_POST` and open your php file in browser for example.

Comment: if you want db error you need to call mysqli_error(connection object) or if it is pdo then use pdo exception to get error.

Comment: I don't know what OS you're on, but I would guess you need F12 and then you can go to the console. There you will see the request and complete response. In Chrome: The menu => More Tools => Developer Tools

Comment: If you are testing it on a Linux machine all you have to do is to keep a terminal open, with the command `tail -f /var/log/apache/error_log` (your path/filename may vary) running, to see all the php errors and warning.